# get current date and date after two months in php

Tags: php, date

this is a very lame question but i m not able to find this one.
How to get today's date and date after two months..

format is month-date-year (numerical.)

Comment: Do you mean add 2 working months (8 working weeks) or do you mean 2 calendar months? Presumably you mean mm-dd-yyyy, but in any case Yanicks answer shows you how to get a unix timestamp from today.

Comment: @Cups yaa but i modified it a little bit to get my requirements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function :

```
$today = time();
$twoMonthsLater = strtotime("+2 months", $today);

// If what you really want is exactly 60 days later, then
$sixtyDaysLater = strtotime("+60 days", $today);
// ...or 8 weeks later :
$eightWeeksLater = strtotime("+8 weeks", $today);
```

In any case, the resulting new timestamps can then be converted to month-date-year :

```
echo 'Today is : ' . date('m-d-Y', $today);
echo 'Two months later will be : ' . date('m-d-Y', $twoMonthsLater);
```

** **UPDATE** **

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php)

> **Note**: Please keep in mind that these functions are dependent on the locale settings of your server. Make sure to take daylight saving time (use e.g. $date = strtotime('+7 days', $date) and not $date += 7*24*60*60) and leap years into consideration when working with these functions.

Just thought I should mention it...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could go about it - the first one would be to do something like this:

```
echo $currentdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());    
echo $after60days = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 60);
```

Basically, you take the current timestamp, expressed in seconds, and add 60 * 60 * 24 * 60, which is the amount of seconds in two months.

Another way to do it, which is my preferred way and how I would do it, is this:

```
$after60days = strtotime("+60 days");
```

The outcome will be exactly the same, $after60days will have a value equal to the timestamp of the day exactly two month from now, but it uses PHP's own strtotime() function.

Of course, if you need to output a date in a format that easy to read for humans, you can do something like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$after60days);
```

Answer (score -2):

Today:

`date('m-d-Y', time());`

Two months from now:

`date('m-d-Y', time() + (86400 * 60));`

Comment: this is not true. '2010-02-01' (Feb. 1, 2010) + 60 days is not exactly two months later. And this does not take into account leap years, etc.