# How do I subtract time in PHP?

Tags: php, time

So, I have the following being returned by an API:

```
<startTime>2011-04-12T01:28:40.000Z</startTime>
```

It's in UTC/Zulu format. How would I go about getting the time elapsed (in seconds) since that timestamp in PHP?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642652/get-current-date-and-date-after-two-months-in-php/3642658#3642658

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime;

$zulu = new DateTime('2011-04-12T01:28:40.000Z');

$difference = $now->diff($zulu);
```

[`diff()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) is supported in >= PHP 5.3.

Otherwise, you can use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
$difference = time() - strtotime('2011-04-12T01:28:40.000Z');
```

Comment: Creating the now DateTime object with `$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` assures that the difference isn't a few hours off if the server's current timezone isn't UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
$now = time();

$zulu = strtotime('2011-04-12T01:28:40.000Z');

$difference = $now - $zulul
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the strtotime (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and time functions (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). Basically you would convert your timestamp to an integer, then subtract it from the current time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$elapsed = time () - strtotime ( $startTime);
```