# Php date and strtotime

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

i have some problem with strtotime , when i try to addimg 2 month to my current date

Example :

```
'2014-12-16 13' => date('Y-m-d H');

$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 13'.'+2 month'));
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: 2014-12-16 13?  what is that 13

Comment: @JelleKeizer Those are the hours I expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get current date and date after two months in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642652/get-current-date-and-date-after-two-months-in-php)

Comment: '2014-12-16 13' => date('Y-m-d H');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it in phpFiddle

It works if you specify minutes (Based on this code)

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 13'.'+2 month'));
```

You said H:i

so if you use:

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 13:00'.'+2 month'));//Note the :00
```

it works for me.

EDIT1:

Without H:i

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2014-12-16'.'+2 month'));
```

EDIT2:

o-W

this works a little for me:

```
$compare_date = date('o-W',strtotime('2014-12-16'.'+2 month'));
```

EDIT3:

As comment says, get rid of dot

```
$compare_date = date('o-W',strtotime('2014-12-16 +2 month'));
```

Comment: but,how we can do it without H:i?

Comment: and if we have date('o-W') how we can combine it with strtotime?

Comment: @YraYra without h:i done

Comment: $compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 13:00 +2 month')); get rid of the .

Comment: no-no,without H:i it's easy

Comment: date('...',strtotime('o-W','...')) 
i asked about it

Comment: the H:i  is only for the date output this would work as well date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 +2 month'));
strtotime just needs time to be written out fully to be working

Comment: @YraYra my edit works a little on phpFiddle, is the output the desired one? O_o

Comment: @YraYra i suppose not, you do have a date in format o-W right?

Comment: @JelleKeizer Removed the useless dot :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) wrong. When using relative time (+2 month) you should provide a timestamp as second parameter (current timestamp is the default value).

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+2 month', strtotime('2014-12-16 13:00')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H',strtotime('2014-12-16 13'.'+2 month'));
```

Instead of:

```
$compare_date = date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('2014-12-16 13'.'+2 month'));
```

Comment: have we another way to do it?
for example

Comment: if i have date('o-W')

Answer (score 0):

Beware with using +month notice the behavior below if the month after has less days

```
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +1 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-03
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +2 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-31
```